# Find bad/duplicate data in same table

Tags: sql

How can I find duplicate data because of bad data entry?
I want to find Customers that have the same PhoneNumber.
I need to list both customers FirstName and LastName

Any thoughts?
Thanks

**Edit**

When I run this query:

```
Select FirstName, LastName, PhoneNumber
From Customer
```

I get this result:

```
Person  One 12345
Person  Two 23456
Third   Person  34567
First   Person  12345
Person  Three   34567
```

**Solution**

This is a version of Bulat's answer, which is best so far. Other answers have not given the result I needed.

```
SELECT
  c1.FirstName as FirstName1,
  c1.LastName as LastName1,
  c2.FirstName as FirstName2, 
  c2.LastName as LastName2,
  c1.PhoneNumber
FROM 
  Customer c1 INNER JOIN 
  Customer c2 ON c1.Phone = c2.Phone AND c1.CustomerID < c2.CustomerID
```

Comment: Which database you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join CUstomers table to itself via Phone Number field like this:

```
SELECT
  c1.Name as Name1,
  c1.Surname as Surname1,
  c2.Name as Name2, 
  c2.Surname as Surname2,
  c.Phone
FROM 
  Customers c1 INNER JOIN 
  Customers c2 ON c1.Phone = c2.Phone AND c1.id < c2.id
```

Note: Unlike other answers this will return customers with same phone number even if their names and surnames do not match.

Answer (score 3):

This query would give you the duplicata

```
select firstname, lastname 
from customers
group by phonenumber, firstname, lastname
having count(phonenumber) > 1
```

- Group all results by phonenumber.
- Display only those who appear more then one time (duplicate).

Comment: What will happen when the customers table has more than one column and OP is not using MYSQL

Comment: Now it is fine. Previously your answer won't work in most of the RDBMS

Comment: @NoDisplayName Yes I realized my mistake, thanks for pointing out.

Comment: This query looks simple and good but it does not give any result on my table and doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 0):

### Duplicate phone numbers:

```
SELECT phone_number
FROM   customers
GROUP
    BY phone_number
HAVING Count(*) > 1
```

### Customers with duplicate phone numbers

```
SELECT *
FROM   customers
 INNER
  JOIN (
        SELECT phone_number
        FROM   customers
        GROUP
            BY phone_number
        HAVING Count(*) > 1
       ) As duplicate_phone_numbers
    ON duplicate_phone_numbers.phone_number = customers.phone_number
```